# React Stateless Functional Components - Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, fsc

I setup a project with laravel as backend Api provider and React as Frontend manager. 
React stateless functional component work well when I simply render some component.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({data:someData})
```

I use useEffect to fetch some data with Axios from an API URL. fine

But when I change the state of a component with setState, it does not work. No change is reflected. it looks like a static page even if I hit 100 times the button which has the click event. the console is clear. No errors

**I want to know why? and how can I fix it.**

Note: *Class based component does not have this problem. it perfectly renders any update of the state*

Some codes

```
const Users = (props) => {

const [state, setState] = useState({

    dataPraticiens: {
        data: [],
        currentPage: 1,
        PerPage: 3
    },
    loaded: false

});


useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('/api/users').then((r) => {

        setState({

            dataPraticiens: {
                data: [...r.data.docs],
                currentPage: 1,
                PerPage: 3
            } ,

            loaded: true
        });

    }).catch((er)=> {
        console.log(er);
    })

},[state.loaded]);

const changePage = (event) => {

    let nS = state;
    nS.dataPraticiens.currentPage = Number(event.target.id);
    nS.loaded = false;
    setState(nS); 
    // log the state and yeah, state changes but not reflected in the page
}


const indexOfLast = state.dataPraticiens.currentPage * state.dataPraticiens.PerPage;

const indexOfFirst = indexOfLast - state.dataPraticiens.PerPage;

const current = state.dataPraticiens.data.slice(indexOfFirst, indexOfLast);


const pageN = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(state.dataPraticiens.data.length / state.dataPraticiens.PerPage); i++) {
    pageN.push(i);
}

const renderPageN = pageN.map(num => {
    return (
        <li
            key={num}
            id={num}
            onClick={changePage} // Not work here.
        >
            {num}
        </li>
    );
});
return (
        {current.map((value, index) => {
           return <React.Fragment key={index}>
                     <li>{value}</li>
                  </React.Fragment>
         })}
        <ul>
          {renderPageN} // pages number`
        </ul>

     )}
```

Comment: Add your code for better understanding.

Comment: Code added. thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like a real functional component. Where are you returning what it should render?

Comment: Thanks for all attention 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `useEffect` you should use an empty array `[]` to indicate that you want the effect to execute only once. Using `[state.loaded]` will reset the state on every state update, since the state update will cause change in `state.loaded` and this change will trigger the effect hook.

Another thing is that you should not mutate the state directly here:

```
let nS = state;
nS.dataPraticiens.currentPage = Number(event.target.id);
nS.loaded = false;
setState(nS);
```

Note that `nS` is just a reference to the same state object, so you technically modifying the state directly which can lead to an undefined behaviors and odd bugs. You should build a new copy of the state object:

```
const newState = {
  dataPraticiens: {
    ...state.dataPraticiens,
    currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
  }, 
  loaded: false
};

setState(newState);
```

From the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

> *NEVER* mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.